# Grabbing hash from URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want it so that if someone visits:

http://www.site.com/#hash

It puts the data after the hash into the input box with the id `url`

and then it submits the form.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="url" placeholder="Enter" name="url">
    <input type="submit" id="visit" value="Visit" class="submit">
</form>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Caution - Differences between browsers! In response to `location.hash`, some will return '#hash' and others just 'hash'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
    if( window.location.hash) {
         var hashVal = window.location.hash.substring(1);
          $("#url").val(hashVal );
      } else {
          alert("no hash found");
      }
```

Comment: you will need to do if( hash.indexOf('#') == 0 ) { hash = hash.substring(0,hash.length); }

Comment: @Shaheer thanks alot for pointing that out, edited the answer

Comment: but you need to add substring only if '#' is present, some browsers wont have it, which will make your current code behave incorrectly.

Comment: Can't I just use `hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');` ?

Comment: @Latox yes you can use that as well

Comment: After reading @Shaheer, this answer seems somewhat lacking or incomplete.  In other words, one would ***have to*** make adjustments to answer based on comments.  I'd up-vote otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  $('#id').val(hash);
  $('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.hash` will give you the hash value from the url. You can use this code.

```
//Instead of empty value set whatever you want in case hash is not present
$("#url").val(window.location.hash || "");
```

Answer (score 0):

try to google for jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js, it needs to be used with jQuery

```
$(window).hashchange(function(){
    $("#url").val(window.location.hash);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to do it - https://github.com/marklar423/jquery.hash it's pretty straightforward.

Example:

```
//get    
var page = $.hash('page');

//set    
$.hash('page', 1);
```