# Find the "#" character in a string with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to parse the given urls via Javascript but I'm not able to use .split() to accomplish to this.

IE:

```
  var str = window.location.pathname;
  var substr = str.split('/');
  alert(substr)
```

If i enter this url "http://mydomain.com/myaddress/page/2/" I have thoose values "myaddress,page,2"

But it doesn't work if instead of / I insert #

Comment: Are you sure `location.pathname` contains a `#`? Usually that is given as `location.hash`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing hash from URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043067/grabbing-hash-from-url)

Answer (score 4):

Use [window.location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location), it gives you that portion broken out.

Also, you're trying to "split" on the `#` character which won't be found in `window.location.pathname`, only `window.location.hash`--unless you use `window.location` and search the entire url.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location). It contains the `#` itself and everything that comes after it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `location.hash` property

Answer (score 0):

if jquery is an option, try the https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser
example

```
var url = $.url('"http://mydomain.com/myaddress/page/2/#lookforme');
alert(url.attr('fragment'));
```