# Can i get the #value on the browser address bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the “#” character in a string with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298328/find-the-character-in-a-string-with-javascript)
>   [How do I get the value after hash (#) from a URL using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662693/how-do-i-get-the-value-after-hash-from-a-url-using-jquery)

Can i get the #value on the browser address bar ? 
For Example from the URL:  http://test.com/#div1 
can i get the div1 from that url using javascript ?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197591/parsing-url-hash-fragment-identifier-with-javascript

Comment: the two link you have give not using "#", but "?" in browser address bar...

Comment: getting two lines from that link only                               var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var vars = query.split("&"); here instead of & u can use #....

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, i wasn't read well... u're great :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.location.hash`.

Comment: thanks, but wait a minute, i will test it... :)

Comment: Sorry, i'll accept it but i must wait 7 minutes... :)